# How to change the span text content using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knouckout-2.2.1 in my application. Its throwing `nodetype` is undefined error but its working fine in knouckout tutorial page. what is the wrong thing here?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewModel = {
                price: ko.observable(24.95)
            };
            viewModel.priceRating = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.price() > 50 ? "expensive" : "affordable";
            }, viewModel);

        // Activates knockout.js
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
<body>
    The item is <span data-bind="text: viewModel.price() > 50 ? 'expensive' : 'affordable'"></span> today.
</body>
```

Any suggestions should be appreciated..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F7E5P/3/ showing that everything works, and changed the way you built you viewmodel a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `ko.applyBindings` call needs to happen after the DOM has loaded. You could do this in something like jQuery's `ready` block or just move your script that calls applyBindings to the bottom of the page.